# Port forwarding my home server problem

Tags: apache-2.2, port-forwarding

I'm trying to set up my laptop as a server for fun.  I got XAMPP, and am running Apache server.  I know it's working, because when I got to localhost, it correctly displays my index.html.  If I go to my local IP, (192.168.1.3), it displays correctly also.  I went into my wireless router, and port forwarded port 5900 to point to my laptop (192.168.1.3) with both UDP and TCP.  I would now assume that if I went to 192.168.1.1:5900 it would point to my new laptop router.  Instead, it says that it cannot establish a connection.  It does the same if I do my router's non-local IP address on port 5900.

Does anyone have any ideas of what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks.

-Ethan

Comment: I presume you've configured the Apache instance in XAMPP to listen on 5900 rather 80?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some reasons this could be happening:

- Your laptop has a firewall running that is blocking incoming requests. Solution: poke a hole in the firewall to allow requests to come in on the correct port (80 or 5900, it's not entirely clear from your question)
- Apache is configured to listen on a specific IP address. For example: `<VirtualHost 192.168.1.3:5900>`. Solution: change it to something like this: `<VirtualHost *:5900>`.
- Apache is listening on the wrong port. ie. not the one your router is forwarding traffic to. For example: `Listen 80`. Solution: change it to something like this: `Listen 5900`.
- Your ISP blocks incoming traffic on port 80. Many ISPs do this. They don't want you running a web site off a cheapo home internet account. They would rather sell you a hosting solution for more money or they simply don't have the upstream bandwidth available to support such things. Solution: see if they offer a business service and pay for that or get a real hosting account from a real hosting company.